# ¿Como realizar el posicionamiento correctamente?

Tags: php

estoy realizando 2 top donde en cada top muestra un resultado diferente, estoy agregando a estos 2 top el posicionamiento lo que sucede es que este me da el posicionamiento mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en las 2 imagenes en la primera el de arriba comienza desde el numero 0 y el de abajo el primero no tiene numero y en la segunda foto el primero esta bien ya que comienza del 1 al 3 pero el segundo el primero no tiene un numero asignado lo que busco es que comience siempre desde el 1 hasta el 5 si este llega a ese conteo

```
<?php while($players_match1 = $query2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    ?>
    <?php if($players_match1['player_team'] == 1)
    {
        $i;
        ?>
        <tr class="<?php if (($i % 2) == 0) { ?>tr_2<?php } else { ?>tr_1<?php } ?>">
            <td><?php echo $i; ?> </td>
            <td>
                <a target="_blank" href="">
                    <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="name">
                <img src="">
                <?php echo $players_match1['player_nombre']; ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match1['player_kills']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match1['player_deaths']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match1['player_headshots']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match1['player_3k']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match1['player_4k']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match1['player_5k']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match1['player_bp']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match1['player_bd']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $hs_porcentaje ?>% </td>
            <td><?php echo $player_adr ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $player_fpr ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
} ?>
```

este es uno y este es el otro

```
<?php while($players_match = $query3->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    ?>
    <?php if($players_match['player_team'] == 2)
    {
        $posicion;
        ?>
        <tr class="<?php if (($posicion % 2) == 0) { ?>tr_2<?php } else { ?>tr_1<?php } ?>">
            <td><?php echo $posicion; ?> </td>
            <td>
                <a target="_blank" href="">
                    <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="name">
                <img src="">
                <?php echo $players_match['player_nombre']; ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match['player_kills']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match['player_deaths']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match['player_headshots']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match['player_3k']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match['player_4k']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match['player_5k']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match['player_bp']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $players_match['player_bd']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $hs_porcentaje ?>% </td>
            <td><?php echo $player_adr ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $player_fpr ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        $posicion++;
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Hola! Disculpa; no es evidente dónde inicializas `$i`

Comment: Cuando hagas una pregunta que busque ayuda con la depuración, es recomendable agregar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), es decir, reducir el código al mínimo para ver únicamente el problema y no todo el código.

Comment: Listo, ya corregí, gracias @Alfabravo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te está funcionando correctamente porque los valores iniciales de `$i` y de `$posicion` no son 1 cuando entras en el `while`. En el caso de `$i` es posible que en otra parte del código sí esté definido como 0, de ahí que en la primera captura empiece como 0 y no vacío como en el caso de la tabla azul.

Una opción para resolverlo sería declarar las variables con valor 1 justo delante del `while` y cambiar levemente el condicional `if (($i % 2) == 0)` por `if (($i % 2) != 0)` para mantener el mismo orden de los estilos, ya que antes el bucle empezaba con número par (0) y ahora empezaría con impar (1):

```
<?php

$i = 1;

while($players_match1 = $query2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    if($players_match1['player_team'] == 1)
    {
        $i; // Esta línea sobra, puedes eliminarla
        ?>
        <tr class="<?php if (($i % 2) != 0) { ?>tr_2<?php } else { ?>tr_1<?php } ?>">
            <td><?php echo $i; ?> </td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
}

?>
```

La otra posibilidad, si no quieres tocar las variables que ya tienes creadas, sería crear una variable específica para ello:

```
<?php

$pos = 1;

while($players_match1 = $query2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    if($players_match1['player_team'] == 1)
    {
        $i; // Esta línea sobra, puedes eliminarla
        ?>
        <tr class="<?php if (($i % 2) == 0) { ?>tr_2<?php } else { ?>tr_1<?php } ?>">
            <td><?php echo $pos; ?> </td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <?php
        $pos++;
        $i++;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchas graciasssss <3 <3 <3